# How to configure application settings in android?

Tags: android, android-xml

In my application I have to keep some setting options for a user, like currency type, language, Calendar view (Either Calendar or List) etc.

Here I am confused whether I have to configure all this by creating database tables or should keep this in any xlm or text file. Please guide if there any more convenient way? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use android [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store a users preferences. Alternatively you can store "global" variables if you create a Application instance which has static or instance variables to access (but these values can be lost if your Activity is destroyed)

The answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables) has details on global application to store application wide variables

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Android has Shared Preference specifically for this purpose.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

You can also look into [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) which helps in building a setting page.