# How to store data in temporary memory

Tags: android

I want the way or the code e.g. to store the value of EditText in the temp variable so when I redirect the activity at that time it stores the value in the temporary variable. When I move back to the activity I can store back it to the EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` may be the easiest way in your case. This is designed for storing a relatively-small amount of data (ballpark practical maximum around 50-100 values) in classic key/value format.

http://androidandandroid.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/android-tutorial-16/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread you want the same thing. [How to configure application settings in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699310/how-to-configure-application-settings-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharedPreferences.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

...

private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

private static final String MY_TEXT_BOX_STRING_KEY = "prefs_textbox_key"

...

mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs",0);

...

// Get the string:

myTextBoxString = prefsGetString(MY_TEXT_BOX_STRING_KEY);

// Set the string:

prefsSetString(MY_TEXT_BOX_STRING_KEY, "blahblah");
```